# die status code vs. normal status code

Tags: php

FILE 1.php :

```
$cmd = 'php asynchronous_script.php -p 1';
$exitCode = 0;
$output = '';
exec($cmd, $output, $exitCode);
echo "\n\n";
echo $exitCode;
print_r($output);
```

FILE asynchronous_script.php :

```
<?
die("**");
```

When I run 1.php, I am getting status code as `0`.

0 is status code for normal execution.

So How can we differentiate between `die` status code vs normal status code?

One solution that I am thinking of is to replace die with `die_with_status_code()`
and implement:

```
function die_with_status_code()
{
    exit(100)
}
```

Is there any better approach for obtaining status code?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `exit(100)` directly?

Comment: Can you explain why you write `die("**")`? Or is just your way of saying it's two digits?

Comment: `die()` is exactly equivalent to `exit()`; providing an integer argument should exit with that status.

Comment: i have die in all my files....... so i need to replace them

Answer (score 0):

*Status code* is simply what the asynchronous_script.php outputs. `die` is an alias for `exit`.

Simply *use* `exit(<your_status_code>)`;

You should rather use `STDOUT` and `STDERR` appropriate.

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'successfully blabla'));
exit(0);
```

From http://php.net/exit :

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.
>   If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254,
>   the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The
>   status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.

Answer to your comment:

You could simply ignore the status code or try implenenting a shutdown handler:

www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: i know status is an option, cant we override die or some other approach in which i dont need to changed code where i hv used die